# Cannot select "Not Now" under Settings>My Name>Start Using iCloud in iOS 11

Tags: ios

A red badge appears on my **Settings** panel right underneath my name next to "Start Using iCloud".

Under **Settings>My Name>Start Using iCloud**, I am given two choices: (1) "Start Using iCloud"; and (2) "Not Now". When I tap "Not Now" nothing happens. I would like to get rid of the badge.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to select "Not Now" I needed to:

1. "Sign Out" under **Settings>My Name**.
2. Connect to the Internet (I used WiFi).
3. Tap "Not Now" under **Settings>Sign in to your iPhone**

Badge gone!